# Angular Form Group reinitialize

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

In Angular 8, I have a Form group where I want to reinitialize the form with new values. But when I do `fb.build` the second time, the values are not displayed correctly.

The checkbox becomes non-checked even though it should be checked and the input field shows `[object Object]`

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <mat-checkbox
      formControlName="dndcheckbox"
      [(ngModel)]="userdetails.DoNotDisturb"
    ></mat-checkbox>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="fwdNumber" [(ngModel)]="userdetails.ForwardNumber" />
    </mat-form-field>
</form>

userdetails: MyObject;
myform: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,) {}

ngOnInit() {
      this.myService.refreshDataSubject.subscribe((data) => {
        this.userdetails = data;
        this.initializeForm();
      });
}

initializeForm() {
    this.myform = this.fb.group({
      dndcheckbox: ['', ''],
      fwdNumber: [
        {
          value: this.userdetails.ForwardNumber,
        },
        control => validateTelephoneNumber(this.userdetails.ForwardNumber),
      ],
    });
}
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: have you check console?, are getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your data. The structure of your userdetails object and the data object that comes from your service that you subscribed is not same. may be data doesn't have the same signature of userdetails. console it to check if it is ok or not.

**Additional**: Your are creating the form every time the data changes but here only the value is changed not the form skeleton. So, I think you can create the form only once and when the data changes just update the form with the new value that comes from your service.

> As, I am not sure about your object structure, Here I assume your service returns data object like this
>   { IsDndChecked: true, ForwardNumber: '123245' }

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();

    this.myService.refreshDataSubject.subscribe((data) => {
      this.userdetails = data;
      this.updateFormValue(data);
    });
  }

  initializeForm() {
      this.myform = this.fb.group({
        dndcheckbox: [''],
        fwdNumber: ['', this.validateTelephoneNumber],
      });
  }

  validateTelephoneNumber(control: AbstractControl) {
    alert(control.value);
  }

  updateFormValue(data: any) {
    this.myform.setValue({
      dndcheckbox: data.IsDndChecked,
      fwdNumber: data.ForwardNumber
    });
  }
```

here Inside `ngOnInit()` I call the method `initializeForm()` to create the form. I am constructing the form once and when the data change `updateFormValue()` is called to update the value of the form.

Another thing, you can set a validator function this way `fwdNumber: ['', this.validateTelephoneNumber]` and no need to pass the value (look I am not sending the value as parameter).

When you update the value of the field (you can update the value from UI or using function like setValue() or patchValue(). for more info about this two function of angular reactive form [see here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value)) the specific control automatically passed to its custom validator function.

If you see the code snippet above, you will find I didn't send any parameter but my method implementation

```
validateTelephoneNumber(control: AbstractControl) {
    alert(control.value);
  }
```

is expecting the particular **fwdNumber** form control.

In this way the code is more cleaner and controllable. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

instead of storing in `this.userdetails` directly pass as a argument to `this.initializeForm(data)`

and reinitialize the value from data arugument

Comment: how does this make a difference?

Comment: Please check the reponse what you stored in  this.userdetails in HTML using {{userdetails | json }} this.



maybe the JSON Loop is differet,

Comment: I've checked the response of userdetails

Comment: Try to change the userdetails type from **MyObject**  to **any** and call the value like this.userdetails['ForwardNumber']